# Show there is a subsequence whose terms are larger than L $+ \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

Show If $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence that has infinitely many terms larger than $L+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon >0$, then there is a subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ all whose terms are larger than $L+\epsilon$

Do I need to use the limit supremum? Or is this just a definition?

Comment: Take exactly those terms larger than $L+\epsilon$; there must be infinitely many of them by hypothesis, so it is a subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually,
a seemingly weaker hypothesis
will suffice:
For any $n$,
there is $m > n$
such that
$a_m 
> L+\epsilon
$.

Using this,
you can,
just as More water plz
showed,
create an infinite subsequence
$a_{n_k}$
with all terms
$> L+\epsilon$.

Comment: Doesn't appear "seemingly weaker" more like "seemingly the same."

Comment: your hypothesis directly implies that there are infinitely many terms larger than $L+ϵ$.

Comment: That is true, but I feel that saying "There is always one more" is weaker than "There are an infinite number", even though the first implies the second.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are infinitely many terms larger than $L+\epsilon$, given any finite $n_i$, there exist some $a_{n_{i+k}}$ such that $a_{n_{i+k}} > L+\epsilon$ for $k>0$.

let $n_1$ be any number such that $a_{n_{1}}>L+\epsilon $. With this $n_1$, there exist some $a_{n_{1+k}} > L+\epsilon$. Now pick $n_2 = n_{1+k}$, and generate $n_3$ in similar way.

Keep doing this and you obtain a sequence {$a_{n_{i}}$} all whose terms are larger than $L+\epsilon$

Comment: Now generalize.  If a sequence $\{a_n\}$ has infinitely many terms with the Donald-Trump property then there must exist a subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ each of whose terms has the Donald-Trump property.